# Creating data structure in Java

Tags: java, class, data-structures, struct

I'm wondering if there is a good way to create a new data structure in Java that avoids creating new class file. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794196/creating-struc-like-data-structure-in-java), the Java's equivalence to struct in **C** is simply a class. However I find it redundant to create a whole new file for a class that simply have a couple of public fields, ex: x,y coordinates of a point. In **C**, the data structure can be defined within the .c file that uses it, which is a lot more simple. Is this actually the only way in Java?

Comment: Use inner classes or multiple classes within the same .java file (of course, with only one public class). But this will still create multiple class files.

Comment: You may even declare a class inside a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [inner/nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). You'll have only one .java file, but nested classes will all have their own .class file when compiling.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a class if you want a data structure. Just to avoid creating multiple .java files, you can put those classes in a single .java file. Assuming, Test.java-

```
public class Test {

    class InnerOne {
    }

    void m() {
        class InnerMost {
        }
    }
}

class Dummy {
}

class OnMore {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create several small, auxiliary classes in one .java file, but they can not be public.
So for example you can create a public class, whose name corresponds to a file and a couple of helper classes that are not public.

As for class per data structure in java, java has only one way of creating abstract data types  - classes, if you're not satisfied with this - try using other JVM languages, like Scala, it is far more flexible in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an Object Oriented Programming language, so everything works with classes and you should not try to program with Java as with C.

If you want to define a data structure within a class, you should use [InnerClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), there is a [good example on the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).