# How to implement an array-like data structure using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I know what arrays are and how to use them. However, I don't know how they are implemented. I was trying to figure out if I can try to implement an array-like data structure using Java but I couldn't.

I've searched online but didn't find anything useful.

Is it even possible to implement an array-like data structure in Java? Is it possible in other languages? if so how (without using arrays of course)?

EDIT: what I want to know is how to implement an array data structure without using arrays?

Comment: yes. you can implement array like data structure in java and other languages[c,c++]

Comment: What is an "array-like data structure", and why are you trying to implement your own? What do you want it for?

Comment: What do you mean an "array-like" structure? Sure, it is possible. create a class which contains an array (type Object). In the constructor, you set the length, or the initial data. Other manipulations go through methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arrays are contiguous sections within memory, so to create an array you would need to reserve a chunk of memory which is of size `n * sizeof(type)`, where `n` is the amount of items you would like to store and the `sizeof(type)` would return the size, in bytes which the JVM would need to represent that given type.

You would then store a reference (pointer) to the first location of your memory segment, say `0x00`, and then you use that as a base to *know* how much you need to move to access the elements, so `a[n]` would be equal to doing `0x00 + (n * sizeof(type))`.

The *problem* with trying to implement this in Java is that Java does not allow pointer manipulation, so I do not think that building your own array type would be possible since you cannot go down to that level.

That being said, you should be able to create a linked data structure, where the `nth` element points to the `(n + 1)th` element.

Other problems why you should try other languages, such as `C#` (check `unsafe` operations), `C++` or `C`:

1. To my knowledge, Java does not have a `sizeof` function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370288/is-there-any-sizeof-like-method-in-java)).
2. Java does not allow `operator overloading`. So you cannot define your own indexing operators such as `[index]`. You would probably need to do something like `array.getElementAt(0)` to get the first element.

As @ug_ recommended, you could take a look at the Unsafe class. But also as he recommended, I do not think that you should do pointer arithmetic with a language which has *pointer abstraction* as one of its core ideas.

Comment: Good answer, but I would point out that you *could* do something silly with the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class that uses memory locations. However doing so would be ill advised.

Comment: @ug_: Thanks for the information. To be honest I did not know that such class existed. Updated answer as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is something like this:

```
MyArray ma = new MyArray(length);
ma[0] = value;
```

Then you can't do this in Java but you can in other languages. Look for "operator overloading".

Comment: You can do this in C# / .NET, you can add an indexing property `[index here]` to your class, so you can do `myClass["foo"]` or `myClass[0]`

Comment: You can do it also in python and other languages. It's up to the OP to look for alternatives fitting his needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your thinking of a structs, vectors or link lists. These are all similar to arrays but are different.

Structs are not really in java, but you can implement them.

Read up on Structs here:
www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

An example Structs used in java:
[Creating struct like data structure in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794196/creating-struct-like-data-structure-in-java)

I think what you are really looking for though are vectors. They are very similar to an array, but their not one.

Vectors info:
www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Array compared to vector:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207308/java-why-do-we-call-an-array-a-vector

I recommend a link list. Its kinda the same idea of an array, but without knowing your exact size. It is easier to implement.

Link lists:
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

All these come down to the situation on what need them for. Saying , "what I want to know is how to implement an array data structure without using arrays?" is kinda open ended.