# Equivalent of C++ struct in Java

Tags: java, c++, struct

I have the following code in C++:

```
struct vec3d
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct triangle
{
    vec3d p[3];
};

struct mesh
{
    vector<triangle> tris;

    bool LoadFromObjectFile(string sFilename) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

How could I translate this into Java? 
Would I use classes for that? So in order to group multiple `vec3d` in a `triangle` :

```
public class vec3d  
{
    float x, y, z;
}

public class triangle  
{   
    vec3d[] p = new vec3d[3];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: I recommend that you not waste too much time trying to use Java  the same way you'd use C++. It leads to much pain. In this case there's an easy way out: `public` members, but things often get fugly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To write a structure in Java, similar would be a class. So yes, you somewhat answered your question.

I believe that this is a better detailed explanation: 
[Creating struct like data structure in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794196/creating-struct-like-data-structure-in-java)

Comment: Don't link to a duplicate in your answer if the question is fully answered by the duplicate. Vote to close as a duplicate instead